# Creating adjacency matrix of topology graph of ArcMap for shortest path using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, spatial-database, topology, vba

I have created a topology graph of a polygon feature and I want to find the individual FIDS of the lines of the polygon. I want to construct an adjacency matrix to create the shortest path. How can I do this with ArcObjects programming with VBA?

Comment: What do you mean by "path" ... is it a sequence of polygons?

Answer (score 2):

The individual lines will now have their own feature ids (they are not features- per se), but you can iterate over the individual Topology edges using [IEnumTopologyEdge](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IEnumTopologyEdge_Interface/0025000002mm000000/) (there is also a sample available).

You can find more information about how to work with Topology Edges here:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002vt000000